# Text translation from the database by codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Use Codeigniter library with language, in the language folder: English, French, etc.

I want to use in database:

```
idproduct | ProductName | ProductNameFR | ProductNameDE
```

Depending on the selected language to take the table to be.

I tried to do like this:
/application/language/English/translateen.php

```
$lang ['ProductName'] = '$info['.'LocatieAdresa'.']; //but not work
```

What other methods recommended to be able to translate the data from the database?

Answer (score 1):

$lang ['ProductName'] = $info['LocatieAdresa'];